# Compare date string with current date?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, comparison

I'm reading a date value from a sql data reader to a string data type variable like this.

```
electionPosDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["elecPODate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

How can I compare it with current system date in an if condition ?

```
if(electionPosDate==_____?)
{

}
```

Comment: *Why* use a string variable to store a date? Use a DateTime and only create a string when you want to display it to the user. If the `elecPODate` field is a date, you don't even need to call `Convert.ToDateTime`, just call `reader.GetDateTime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Date` property of `DateTime`, if you want to check for Date part only, and for getting current date use `DateTime.Now`, but for only date part use `DateTime.Now.Date`:

```
DateTime electionPosDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["elecPODate"]);   
if(electionPosDate.Date ==DateTime.Now.Date)
{

}
```

See [MSDN docs for Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Ehsan.Sajjad electionPosDate is string type variable how can I convert it to DateTime data type?

Comment: @SonerGönül it shouldn't be. Using strings instead of dates is a common source for bugs and questions to SO

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeap, it definitly shouldn't be. But in OP case, it is :)

Answer (score 7):

Since `electionPosDate` is a `string`, not a `DateTime`, you need to compare it like;

```
if(electionPosDate == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

**But more important,** I feel you are doing something wrong. If `elecPODate` column is *already* `datetime` typed, you can just use [`SqlDataReader.GetDateTime` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value as a `DateTime`. In your case, you are parsing your `string` to `DateTime` and after that, you convert it to `string` again. This is totally unnecessary. You should always choose the best column type that fits your data types.

For example, if this `elecPODate` column is the first column or your reader, you can just use;

```
DateTime electionPosDate = reader.GetDateTime(0);
```

and compare it like;

```
if(electionPosDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Please read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Far better to make `electionPosDate` a DateTime variable. I doubt this is the only place where using the wrong type will create issues

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right, at first, `elecPODate` column should be date typed, not character typed. Updated my answer, thanks.